# How to get a number from the end of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still kind of new to Ruby and I'm a bit stuck.
I would need to get a number off of the end of a string.
Lets say i have the string "potato85" and i would need the 85.
The number of digits in the number can vary like it could be "potato8" - "potato8585".
Is there any way i can split the string and get the first part and the number?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Use the String#scan Method

You can use the [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) method. For example:

```
my_string = 'potato8585'
my_string.scan( /\d+$/ ).first
# => "8585"

my_string = 'potato8'
my_string.scan( /\d+$/ ).first
# => "8"
```

This method will read all the possible matches in a string into an array, but the `$` anchor will ensure there's only one element. Then, just pop the first element from the array to return a string.

There are other ways to do this, but this seems like the simplest solution to me. YMMV.

Comment: This is really good too, a bit more elegant than with reversal. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: `"ab23\ncd42".scan(/\d+$/).first` is 23. `"ab23\ncd42".scan(/\d+\z/).first` is 42.

Comment: @undur_gongor Yes. If you're going to have multi-line strings, then `\z` means "end of string" while `$` means "end of line." This may or may not matter for most use cases--it certainly doesn't matter for the provided corpus--but it's an important distinction. While my answer addresses the original corpus, one should feel free to substitute the anchor based on the input characteristics of the data. --Alternatively, you could use Array#last instead, if you don't expect your array element to be the first (or only) match.

Comment: @undur_gongor `'abc123 def456\nghi789'.scan(/\d+\b/)` is a more generic matcher anyway, but in this case it will return an array of three elements. The problem with any regex is that you have to know your data well enough to know which anchors you need, and which elements you need to extract. That's why a corpus provided by the OP is so important to regular expression questions. YMMV.

Comment: @CodeGnome: I think you should always use `\z` when you want to match the end of string. Using `$` just because -- in this case -- end of line happens to be end of string is an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it:

```
"potato85".reverse.to_i.to_s.reverse.to_i # => 85
```

But you probably want to use a regex.

Answer (score 1):

I would using a regular expression with .match() More here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

Using a little Regular Expression will get you what you need. Check this out:

```
[1] pry(main)> r = /(.*?)(\d+)$/
=> /(.*?)(\d+)$/
[2] pry(main)> m = r.match "potato8"
=> #<MatchData "potato8" "potato" "8">
[3] pry(main)> m = r.match "potato85"
=> #<MatchData "potato85" "potato" "85">
[4] pry(main)> m = r.match "potato8585"
=> #<MatchData "potato8585" "potato" "8585">
[5] pry(main)> m = r.match "p0t4to8585"
=> #<MatchData "p0t4to8585" "p0t4to" "8585">
[6] pry(main)> m[1]
=> "p0t4to"
[7] pry(main)> m[2].to_i
=> 8585
```

So `(.*?)` matches any number of any characters non-greedily and `(\d+)$` then matches 1 or more digits at the end of the string.